# Java 8: Optional против if else. Что быстрее?

Tags: java, производительность, optional

С введением в Java 8 новой конструкции Optional у меня возникли разногласия с коллегами по поводу скорости работы Optional vs if-else vs тернарный оператор. Несколько примеров:

Java 8:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(user)
         .map(User::getUserSurname)
         .orElse("None");
```

Старый добрый вариант:

```
if (user != null && user.getUserSurname() != null) {
    return user.getUserSurname();
}

return "None";
```

Тернарный вариант:

```
return (user != null && user.getUserSurname() != null) ?
        user.getUserSurname() : "None"
```

P.S. Интересно было бы проверить и для более глубокой вложенности

```
return Optional.ofNullable(user)
         .map(User::getUserDetails())
         .map(User::getUserSurname())
         .orElse("None");
```

Comment: С моей точки зрения, вопрос о нанооптимизациях имеет смысл рассматривать лишь в числомолотильном коде (и если каждый такт процессора важен, то Java — слишком высокоуровневый язык). А нормальном коде намного большее значение имеет _семантика_ (то ли вы пишете, что при этом думаете) и _читаемость_ (правильно ли вы доносите вашу мысль тем, кто будет поддерживать ваш код). // А эффективность может вполне поменяться с улучшением оптимизации в вашем компиляторе.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле лаконичней код или нет - личное дело каждого. Решающее значение обычно имеет производительность (если, конечно, это важно для проекта). По поводу производительности могу привести следующие результаты:

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units

MyBenchmark.ifElse              avgt  200  2.717 ± 0.036  ns/op
MyBenchmark.ifElseNullField     avgt  200  2.733 ± 0.045  ns/op
MyBenchmark.ifElseNullObject    avgt  200  2.789 ± 0.025  ns/op

MyBenchmark.optional            avgt  200  3.020 ± 0.042  ns/op
MyBenchmark.optionalNullField   avgt  200  5.570 ± 0.069  ns/op
MyBenchmark.optionalNullObject  avgt  200  2.936 ± 0.060  ns/op
```

Соответственной проверялся код из вопроса с несколькими вариантами:

- с ненулевым объектом и ненулевым полем объекта
- с ненулевым объектом и *нулевым* полем объекта
- с *нулевым* объектом

О результатах судить не стану, дабы не развивать холивар.

Comment: Спасибо за бенчмарки! Чем мерили ?

Comment: @Damintsew JMH конечно

Comment: Если бы решающей была производительность, Java никогда не появилась бы, а мы все до сих пор сидели бы на Ассемблере.

Comment: ну это уже демагогия. Я не прошу сравнить ассемблер/с/с++ и java, а вопрос чисто по java и конструкциям языка

Comment: эти цифры никогда не повторятся в реальном проекте https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721811/2908793